# UWP C# radiobutton Event CheckedChanged

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm looking for an event which triggers when any radiobutton in a group changes the status.

In WPF or Forms I use CheckedChanged.

In UWP it doesn't exist. Is there an equivalent to it?

Comment: The events for a UWP Radio Button are located in the [ToggleButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton) class.

Comment: Thanks, it works now with the event "Click"